# how can I relate two selectManyListbox?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I'am using JSF2.0/primefaces ,I have two  selectManyListbox

```
   <h:selectManyListbox   value="#{ToolsJIRA.selectedProjects}"  size="3">
      <f:selectItems value="#{ToolsJIRA.getMyListProject()}" />

     </h:selectManyListbox>

      <h:selectManyListbox   value="#{TestAjax.selectedstatus}" size="3">
      <f:selectItems value="#{TestAjax.StepsByProject()}" />
     </h:selectManyListbox>
```

the second selectManyListbox is related to the first selectManyListbox (when user choose options from the first the second will be filled),
How can I relate them?

Comment: Check out this tutorial [Implementing a Cascading DropDown with JSF 2](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/lamineba/archive/2011/05/12/implementing-cascading-dropdown-jsf-2-0)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`<f:ajax>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html).

```xml
<h:selectManyListbox value="#{bean.selectedProjects}" size="3">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableProjects}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.updateAvailableSteps}" render="steps" />
</h:selectManyListbox>

<h:selectManyListbox id="steps" value="#{bean.selectedSteps}" size="3">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableSteps}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

with something like

```
public void updateAvailableSteps() {
    availableSteps = new ArrayList<Step>();

    for (Project selectedProject : selectedProjects) {
        availableSteps.addAll(selectedProject.getSteps());
    }

    // If you want to filter duplicates, add the following line as well:
    // availableSteps = new ArrayList<Step>(new LinkedHashSet<Step>(availableSteps));
}
```

In input components, the `<f:ajax>` fires by default on every `change` event. When fired, the bean method as declared in `listener` attribute will be invoked and the component(s) as definied in `render` attribute will be updated.